# In Dspace7 how to create a new endpoint

Tags: spring-boot, dspace

Is anyone know how to create an new endpoint in dspace7. Where i have tried to create a new controller but it was not creating (my sample endpoint : /api/custom/create) I want to create like this.

I want to create an new endpoint in dspace in that I don't want to pass any permissions like admin or anonymous